# select2 : cannot read property query of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have create javascript like this

```
$(document).on("select2:open", ".provider_suggestion", function() {
    $(this).select2({
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        ajax: {
            url: "../include/suggestion/provider_name.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function(params){ return { q: params.term }; },
            processResults: function (data, page) { return { results: data }; },
            cache: true
        }
    });
});
```

and create select html input like this

```
<select id="c_providers" name="c_providers" class="provider_suggestion" style="width:100%"></select>
```

and when page loaded, I click the select input.

I open the browser console, its mentioned that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null

I still dont understand about this issue.

Comment: Not really enough information to answer. The property name 'query' doesn't appear anywhere in your provided code. Does it appear elsewhere in your code, attached to an object that can accidentally be null? If not, it is used in select2 code somewhere, and you are providing invalid arguments. Does the stack trace show any of your own code? That would be the place to start looking...

Comment: @Thernys the error is on the browser console, when I click the select form.

Comment: I understand that. The browser console should also provide you with a stack trace to hopefully see where in your code the problem originates.

Comment: its error is from the plugin, not from my code as above.

Answer (score 1):

You must have already initialized the select2 somewhere previous to your provided code snippet, or I expect the `select2:open` listener would never fire and cause your problem. When I replicated the situation in a fiddle and peeked at the select2 source, it seemed that select2 was complaining about a `dataAdapter` being null, which must be a side effect of this double select2() call, or that the .select2() call is inside the listener with an unexpected context... Or something, don't have the time or interest to explore down to the root cause.

Regardless, moving the .select2() call out of the listener (and removing the then empty listener) removed the problem. Based on the limited information available in your question, it does not seem like there is any need at all to use this listener, at least the way you are using it. A simplistic working example is in [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7x9zwuq/), where the only real difference to your original code is the removal of the listener wrapping (and the mocking of AJAX calls). So, try something like

```
$('#c_providers').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
        url: "../include/suggestion/provider_name.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function(params){ return { q: params.term }; },
        processResults: function (data, page) { return { results: data }; },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

as the only select2 initialization for this `#c_providers` element.

Comment: yes @Thernys currently my code is `$('#c_providers').select2({})` but i want to do in `$(document).on("select2:open", ".provider_suggestion", function() {})` its not worked.. :(

Comment: @Jin why do you want to do it in the open listener / what exactly is it you are trying to achieve...

Comment: well, I am trying to load the form with ajax, and the form contain select input, and I want to use it with select2, but it doesnt work with `$(document).on("select2:open", ".provider_suggestion", function() {})`

Comment: @Jin please edit your question with more relevant code. How is the form 'loaded with ajax' and inserted to DOM, etc. If you instead just mean you want the select2 values to be populated with AJAX, then you only need to initialize the select2 as in my answer, no need for the `select2:open` listener.