# How to populate a Select2 element on open event through an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have the following code in a Twig template:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>License ID</th>
        <th>Quote ID</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for key,value in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ value.id }}</td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control select2" data-placeholder="--Select One--"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The code above translate into one or more SELECT elements depending on the data coming from the backend.

Each of those will need to run a **really BIG and slow query** to get the data that should be there.

What I am thinking is to render them just empty (no values at all, just the initial placeholder) and when I open each of them then populate it's data so I run just one query at a time (thru AJAX).

I should also - although don't know if it's a good idea (you tell me) - on close destroy all the SELECT values.

> Note: I should say the Select2 elements are contained in a jQuery UI dialog but this shouldn't be a problem.

This is how my code looks like:

```
addtoquoteDialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        "Add to Quote": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var $select2selector = $('.select2');
        $select2selector.select2();
        $select2selector.on('select2:open', function (e) {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $select2selector.select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: Routing.generate('quote_select_data', {id: id}),
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            });
        }).on('select2:closing', function (e) {
            // Destroy the select values
        });
    }
});
```

But I am raising the `Cannot read property 'query' of null` famous error message and the AJAX call is not being triggered.

I've seen a lot of issues like this ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016655/select2-cannot-read-property-query-of-null) for example) but none seems to be like mine so I am completely lost.

Can any tell me what I am missing in my code?

<strike>I am seeing [this example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data) but this happen when the SELECT get's initialized, I am right?</strike>

<strike>What is the right way to handle this?</strike>